# Zero sized reply: PHP crashing on variable assignment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I occasionally got a problem, which lets the webbrowser display the message "Zero sized reply" (Firefox). Chrome displays "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". I am using CodeIgniter (still a version 2.xx).

On the call, I validate some post variables, insert a database record, and send an email. The email method however loads a language file for a log message. On the end of this call, in the class system/core/Lang.php, the file gets included and a class array is extended.

The following line (Lang.php, line 126), executes the following statement:

```
$this->is_loaded[] = $langfile;
```

The array is initialized and this usually functions just fine. But in this special case, this is the exact line which leads the PHP server to crash (my explanation for the empty response I get).

I am running now forced PHP 5.5.19, but the error also displays with 5.2.17.

Anyone an explanation why this happens? If I try to reproduce the error by assigning a variable in a similar way, I never recieve the same message. Also, the only similarity in cases I recieve this error is that I've sent a mail before.

**Update**: Here's the PHP_INFO: http://awesumgrades.ch/phpinfo.php

**Update 2**: Here's what I tried exactly:

I tried to dump everything before that line:

```
var_dump($this->is_loaded);
var_dump($langfile);
exit("I reached here");
$this->is_loaded[] = $langfile;
```

Recieving this output:

```
array(0) { } string(14) "email_lang.php" I reached here
```

Now when I execute this (put the array assignment in front):

```
$this->is_loaded[] = $langfile;
var_dump($this->is_loaded);
var_dump($langfile);
exit("I reached here");
```

I get an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` (chrome).

When I dump `$this`, this is the object:

```
object(CI_Lang)#11 (2) { ["language"]=> array(0) { } ["is_loaded"]=> array(0) { } }
```

When I go a step back to the calling function, I got the following lines (at core/libraries/Email.php):

```
protected function _set_error_message($msg, $val = '')
{
    $CI =& get_instance()
    $CI->lang->load('email'); // <-- this is the call which gets to the other method
```

I put the following lines in front of the email loader:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
var_dump($this);
var_dump($CI);
exit();
$CI->lang->load('email');
```

This outputs the whole object, which I cannot post here because of security reasons of my site. If you need a specific property or a part of the object, I'll provide here.

I'm currently still waiting for the Apache Log from my hoster, if it's here I'll post it.

**Update 3**: I've just tried to simply comment out the line once again, but then the script crashes at the following line, which clarifies that the crash has absolutely nothing to do with the logic of the class Lang.php, but it seems to be an error of a bigger class (I've tried to print out the memory but I don't have permission for `memory_get_usage()`....

## **FINAL UPDATE**

I've finally reached my hoster which provided me the apache error logs, but there weren't any clues of the said error.

However, the magic is now complete: After [smcjones'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1935338/smcjones) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394717/zero-sized-reply-php-crashing-on-variable-assignment#answer-33551793), I added the line

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at the very first line in CI's index.php, and set the error_reporting again to E_ALL. However, as soon as I run the code with this line set, the error won't happen again - even when I set `display_errors` to `0`. When I comment the line out again, the error happens again. Also when I remove the `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, the error occurrs, despite the ini_set.....

I got absolutely no clue what gets changed with these lines, but it seems like with the call of [ini_set()](http://php.net/ini_set) and the error_reporting, some routine maybe gets included which was missing otherwise - I don't know.

It states once more how [magic PHP sometimes can be](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) - it never fails to amaze me.

Comment: if php was crashing, you'd get a 500 server error, or indications of it in the server's error log. just because php doesn't output anything doesn't mean it's "crashing".

Comment: @MarcB if it did not crash I'd recieve a blank page (try a PHP file which does not output anything), but not the empty response error.

Comment: then turn on error_reporting and display_errors, and start debugging.

Comment: @MarcB that's turned on :) this is why I had to comment every line out to find out on which line the error happens. Error reporting is set to report all errors, but there is literally no response at all, not even the error. No possibility to catch the error.

Comment: well, simply doing a variable assignment is HIGHLY unlikely to crash php, unless you're so very memory constrained that one more array entry pushes you over the top.

Comment: @MarcB i also considered that and tried to fill some more memory before that statement, yet it did not crash just up to this line.

Comment: You've singled-out `Lang.php, line 126` as the source of the error. Why? Do you e.g. have a more detailed error message that points to that line of code? Or have you tried around excluding/including code fragements until you found that line to be the single step to trigger the error? Or is it a "I never liked that line of code anyway" guess?  ;-)

Comment: That error indicates that an http request did not reply. Technically, it means that the web process handling your request closed the connection without returning any data at all, not even HTTP headers. (It sent a "zero-sized reply.")  I don't believe it has anything to do with Lang.php. You just happens to be when the 'zero-size' message came back. Probably associated with the mail sending process somehow.

Comment: Is the Squid  caching proxy running on the server that is sending out your email?

Comment: @VolkerK I can prove with excluding / including lines that it is exactly this line that causes the error. I can remove it and everything works fine. I can set another class variable at the same place to a string value, and it also crashes. I got no error logs from my hoster, neither do I recieve anything cause the code below this line does not get executed. DFriend, I don't know Squid and I can't find anything about it in my PHP info, so I don't know.

Comment: see if this help in https://vimeo.com/60824619 `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 if it was a PC problem, I would not recieve the error on different PCs nor would it work if I comment out that line.

Comment: Which kind of web server are you using?

Comment: @hek2mgl I've updated the post with the PHP-Info link, there you should be able to recieve all infos

Comment: You are running PHP as CGI. Run the script from the command line using the `php-cgi` interpreter, you should be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @hek2mgl  I don't have access to the server's command line :/

Comment: Then you need to install the stack on your computer, or on a computer you own.

Comment: It is unlikely that the problem is caused by PHP alone. You can reproduce this behavior by creating PHP file with `sleep();` in it (e.g. `sleep(20);`), open it and kill the Apache process serving the request (or the entire Apache). So, what could be the problem in your case is that your script generates some error which causes the Apache process handling the connection to be killed (and by killed this means SIGKILL). This is likely to be a problem with your host. If the problem is 100% reproducible you can ask your host to provide you with a trace of the Apache process handling the connection.

Comment: As a Codeigniter lover i never face this kind of thing. Can you post your code as well an add some more detail about what you include? how you validate? how its work and all. If you can provide those I will give nice solution.

Comment: @hek2mgl the signature says `Server Apache`

Comment: @FlorianMüller could you please add more details here? Log output, errors, code?

Comment: @sitilge No, it clearly says: `Server API:  CGI/FastCGI `

Comment: @sitilge I'll prove more detail this evening when I'm at home

Comment: @hek2mgl no, it is `Server API Apache 2.0 Handler `

Comment: @hek2mgl and (I guess) there is should be a difference between API (cgi, fcgi,...) and "kind" (nginx, apache,...) ? Or am I getting smth wrong? :)

Comment: @sitilge Yes, there is. And I'm talking about the SAPI which is 'CGI/FastCGI' in this case. I would start to debug this independently first.

Comment: @sitilge I've updated my question with the details I could provide. If you need something else, let me know what ;)

Comment: Two quick questions: (1) Which language is set in your `APPPATH/config/config.php`?  (2) In Lang.php, what is the value of `$idiom`?

Comment: That line may be *triggering* a crash, but is 100% NOT where the problem comes from. I'd debug the email library calls ... and I suspect a problem with `mail()`.

Comment: @NigelTufnel Language is by default `english` (did not change). Idiom is `string(7) "english"`

Comment: Thanks.  Like others, I suspect the problem isn't with the array assignment, but with the email.  I just wanted to confirm the environment.  What mail protocol are you using? `$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';` for example.  If you are using Sendmail, try testing with *SMTP*.

Comment: @NigelTufnel I'm using PHPs standard `mail()`, I don't have an SMTP server.

Comment: Ok.  Even if you don't have a production SMTP server available, hopefully you have a Gmail account you can use temporarily to prove/disprove `mail()` as the culprit.  `$config['smtp_host']   = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';`
`$config['smtp_port']   = 465;`
`$config['smtp_user']   = 'user@gmail.com';`
`$config['smtp_pass']    = 'yourpass';`
should be sufficient to send through Gmail via SMTP and bypass your local mail facilities.

Comment: @NigelTufnel I tried it and with SMTP, it actually runs without error, while when I switch back to mail() the error is reproducable. Therefore, there has to be a correlation with the mail function used (see my final edit in the post).

Comment: I agree that the problem lies in the mail function.  Are you using CI's email class or PHP's native `mail()` function?  If you use CI's email class, try `sendmail` next.  Your phpinfo() shows a path to the sendmail binary.

Comment: @NigelTufnel as you can see at the answer of smcjones, this has a dependancy on the `error_reporting` and the `ini_set` calls, so the behaviour lies definitely in the `mail()` configuration of the hoster. However, as a first step I will try to use SMTP of my hoster, and I'll wait for future PHP releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your log level is not high enough to receive non-fatal errors. PHP can just gracefully shut down if there is an error that isn't set to display.

I understand that you should be receiving errors based on your CI configuration, but you may not be receiving warnings. Any warnings you get could serve as a clue.

Please try putting this at the top of your file (before any output and headers):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

When you refresh your browser, you should not receive an empty page.

Another thing you can try, as a slightly better long-term patch, is:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

If this works, then stick with that for now because it is less likely to show the user things you don't want them to see.

Ultimately, based on the behavior changing (incorrectly) when using PHP configuration functions, this is something either Apache related or PHP config related, which is host-specific. Because you can't handle your host, I recommend switching hosts (there are lots of good affordable host options) or at least telling your host you won't be able to stay with them unless they fix whatever is wrong.

Comment: You are f***ing kidding........
With just the change of setting `ini_set('display_errors',1)` at the very first line of code, the error won't happen again. Seriously? I've double-tripple checked that the exact same lines of code are run! When I comment the ini_set out, the error occurrs again! Like he was like "oh darn, he wanna see the errors, better not produce them..."
Freaking magic.

Comment: It's probably a server error. You'd figure hosts would be rock solid but a lot of them aren't.

Comment: It wasn't just that line - it was the combination of `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set()` which leads to a working variant. When I remove one of these two, the script fails again.....

Comment: That's something I'd recommend you share with your host and/or look for a different host. That is abnormal behavior which almost definitely points to a server error.

Comment: I edited my answer and included another thing to test and recommended next steps.

Comment: With `E_ERROR`, the error occurs, with `E_ALL` it won't. Wizzard get out, it's no more fun... ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Lang.php` file is use to load error messages which belongs to your library and helper which we load.

**Why??**

```
Path - `system/language/english`
```

In above path(go to `email_lang.php`) you can see there are some error message. So when we use the library,
we use `echo $this->email->print_debugger();` this to print error messages which we able to see on browser.
Actually all this error messages are comes from here.

**How??**

```
Path - `system/language/english`
```

In above path you can check there are multiple files which end up with suffix `_lang.php`. So in `lang.php` file(you can check that in `lang.php` -  line 65-132)
they remove all suffix `_lang` and `.php`. So finally it load the file with just helper name. If `email_lang.php` it will return just `email`.
So finally it will load file to `$this->is_loaded[] = $langfile;` and this will set to `print_debugger`

**Any reason??**

As simple CI tricks we use `$this->email` for our mailling purpose. Actually In here `email` containe two diferet files/methods.

1. E-Mail Helper (which we load throug `$this->load->library('email');`)
2. lang file support (which we load throug `lang.php`)

so this both combine to give us one service.

**Is this will affect my CI Project?**

No. Bcz this will load weh we use library only.

You may question **Is this hangs when use the library?**.
**Ohh Never**. When you open the file, you can see there is only some sort of error messages. There is no functions,
no arithmatical operetions, etc.. just and array value with some sort of error.

---

**Dont use**

```
  var_dump($this->is_loaded);
  var_dump($langfile);
```

1. when you this some times browser hangs. Bcz you are loading an object.
2. As well as don't use `dump()` it will not good at all.

Answer (score -1):

There are not many clues to solve your problem :S Anyway, I think that probably you are getting a PHP error, and because that line is so small I think that the cause of the problem is that you are trying to add an item to a nonexistent array. I should try:

```
if (is_array($this->is_loaded)) {
    $this->is_loaded[] = $langfile;
}
```

To try to find more info about the problem:

- Could you enable the development environment in the top level index.php?

  ```
  define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
  ```
- Could you enable the CodeIgniter profiler?

  ```
  $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
  ```
- Could you take a look to the apache error log?

Comment: I did still not recieve the apache log from my hoster, but the `ENVIRONMENT` is set by default on `development` at my site ;)

Comment: Answers should answer the question! (Comments are appropriate when asking for more information on the question.) Also, PHP will happily create an array when it comes across the `$undeclared_variable[] = 1;` construct.